# Method of coding to find the mean and standard deviation

Tags: statistics

The mass of each of 300 packets of flour produced by a factory in labelled 1kg. When the mass of each packet is measured to the nearest $0.001$ kg, the following frequency distribution is obtained.
Calculate the mean mass of the packet.

[image: Table]

My question is how to find the equation $y$? The answer given for equation $y$ is $200(x-1.0025)$

Comment: What do $y$ and 200 represent?